# How can i return the longest continuous occurrence of "True" in Boolean, and replace other True with False?

Tags: python, numpy, more-itertools

I am trying to return a boolean which only gives the longest "True" occurrence in the original boolean and replace shorter "True" chunks into "False". Example a=[True, True, False, True , True, True, False], i want to return [False, False, False, True, True, True, False].

i tried more_itertools and it seems to have some interesting functions but not sure how to exactly implement for my purpose.

```
a=[True, True, False, True , True, True, False]

pred = lambda x: x in {True}

p=list(mit.run_length.encode(a))

>>>
Results in: (True,2),(False,1),(True,3),(False,1)
```

So what i want to eventually automatically get is (False,3),(True,3),(False,1). any suggestions?
Thank you for your help

Comment: Where is the function `mit.run_length.encode` defined? Also could you explain your output

Comment: @ Devesh Kumar Singh the link is here:https://more-itertools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html i guess it is in version 4. I had to install it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Below solution should work after using [more_itertools.run_length](https://more-itertools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#more_itertools.run_length).

Essentially, the logic is to find the length of longest subsequence of True, and the location of that index in `result` list
then count the total elements before and after that longest subsequence, then construct the resultant list of tuples accordingly.

```
import more_itertools as mit

a=[True, True, False, True , True, True, False]

result = list(mit.run_length.encode(a))

#Find the length of longest subsequence of True, and the location if that index in result
max_true_count = -1
max_true_idx  = -1
for idx, (val, count) in enumerate(result):
    if val and max_true_count < count:
        max_true_count = count
        max_true_idx = idx

#Find total elements before and after the longest subsequence tuple
elems_before_idx = sum((idx[1] for idx in result[:max_true_idx]))
elems_after_idx = sum((idx[1] for idx in result[max_true_idx+1:]))

#Create the output list using the information
output = [(False, elems_before_idx), (True, max_true_count), (False, elems_after_idx)]
print(output)
```

The output will be

```
[(False, 3), (True, 3), (False, 1)]
```

Comment: Im trying this a=[(False, 22), (True, 62), (False, 10), (True, 4), (False, 102)], but the result is weirdly [(False, 94), (True, 4), (False, 102)]. Can you kindly verify this??

Answer (score 2):

Here's a vectorized one -

```
def keep_longest_true(a):
    # Convert to array
    a = np.asarray(a)

    # Attach sentients on either sides w.r.t True
    b = np.r_[False,a,False]

    # Get indices of group shifts
    s = np.flatnonzero(b[:-1]!=b[1:])

    # Get group lengths and hence the max index group
    m = (s[1::2]-s[::2]).argmax()

    # Initialize array and assign only the largest True island as True.
    out = np.zeros_like(a)
    out[s[2*m]:s[2*m+1]] = 1
    return out

def island_info(a):
    '''' Get island tuple info
    '''

    # Attach sentients on either sides w.r.t array start and end
    b = np.r_[~a[0],a,~a[-1]]

    # Get group lengths and group start elements
    lens = np.diff(np.flatnonzero(b[:-1] != b[1:]))
    grpID = np.resize([a[0],~a[0]],len(lens))

    # zip those two info for final o/p
    return zip(grpID,lens)
```

Sample run -

```
In [221]: a
Out[221]: [True, True, False, True, True, True, False]

In [222]: keep_longest_true(a)
Out[222]: array([False, False, False,  True,  True,  True, False])

In [223]: island_info(keep_longest_true(a))
Out[223]: [(False, 3), (True, 3), (False, 1)]
```

Comment: This pretty easy and simple as well. Thank you.